# Anti-windup scheme for PID controller

Tags: control, pid-controller, integrator

this is the designed pid controller and i am using TL084 op-amps which has +15 volts and -15 volts as their supply. when the error is generated, due to integrator the control signal(Vc) output is going to saturation point of nearly 15 volts. I want Vc to be in the range of (0.85-3.8 volts), so that i can give this to SG3524 PWM IC to generate constant duty ratio PWM pulses. I tried by putting zener diode of 3.3 volt rating, but now Vc is coming upto 3.5 volts(basically saturation limit has come down to 3.5 volts) . The problem is how to limt the Vc to the specified range.
Can any one please suggest modifications for proper design of anti-windup  working scheme of this. 
Here VFb=-3 volts and VRef= 3 volts[image]

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not add the information in the "Answers" area, and do not create a duplicate question.